# Changing flow type stops it updating records

Tags: visual-workflow

I took a copy of a record triggered flow and used Save As and advanced to change the type of flow to an autoactivated one. After I'd done this the flow seemed to stop working - it didn't update the Contact as the previous version had. Why is this?

(Note that after I'd done that I had to do some fiddling so that the new flow knew which record to run itself with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of a subtle change in the Update Records element at the end of the flow, presumably because it is no longer record triggered and so some of the options don't apply. The original version had these options:

[image]

whereas the new version had these options for the Update Records element:

[image]

It defaulted to the top option, which didn't actually update the record. Instead I had to choose "specify conditions..." and then set the field that was supposed to change.

Comment: If this subtle change was due to Salesforce release (you created the flow on release X, edited on release Y), it'd be helpful to have that in your answer.

Comment: I think the change was more due to the type of flow it was, so I've put some wording above to make that clear: " presumably because it is no longer record triggered and so some of the options don't apply"